# How to generate dummy variables from two categorical variables?

Tags: stata

I have two variables containing state identifier and year. If I want to create dummy variables indicating each state, I usually write the following code:

```
tab state_id, gen(state_id_)
```

This will give me a group of variables, state_id_1,state_id_2,... etc. But what operations are available if I want to get a list of dummy variables for the interaction of state and year, for instance a dummy variable indicating state 1 in year 2005.

Comment: Perhaps you can be helped by Stata's factor variable notation, which in general eliminates needing to explicitly create dummy variables. So if you are not familiar with factor variables, you might review section 11.4.3 of the Stata User's Guide PDF included with your Stata installation (for version 11 and later) and accessible from Stata's Help menu, and see if their use will solve your problem. Methodologically, factor variables let Stata's commands (especially `margins`) understand the relationship between dummies: if state_id_23==1 then all the others must be 0.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Thanks for the comment. It's very helpful. I am familiar with the factor variable, bu I always thought it is equivalent to the dummy variables generated manually. Apparently, factor variables have extra information,compared to dummy variables. And this difference leads to different convergence path in MLE estimations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at `xi` (https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rxi.pdf)? It will create dummies for each of the categorical variables and for the interaction of those two. So if you do:

```
 xi i.state*i.year
```

This should give you what you are looking for, but note that it will naturally code this and omit the first category of each of your categorical variables.

Comment: Yes. I have looked at it. It does half the job. I need to generate two sets of interactions. One is state with year interactions, another is area with year interactions. When I use the xi command the second time on the same dataset to generate area with year interactions, it drops all state with year interactions.

Comment: It seems that xi with a prefix option solves my follow-up question.

Comment: This is doing things the old-fashioned way and is generally preferable only if your version of Stata does not support factor variable notation. The comment by @William Lisowski is bang on in that respect.